# Why I can't malloc function in between a code given below?? PS:- COMMENT LINES

Tags: malloc

why can't i declarer a new variable in the 4th linen using malloc function 
compiler gives an error "Cannot create a new node".

```
         while(a>0)
         {  struct node*newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
         printf("Enter the data in the node\n");
         scanf("%d",&b);
         struct node*newnodee=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
         newnode->data=b;
```

Comment: The `struct node` is not known to the compiler at this point, maybe you forgot to include a header? There is also an error in line 19, it should be `malloc(sizeof(struct node))`, without `*`!.

Comment: Please format your code properly and tag it with the language you're using (looks like C).

Answer (score 0):

"#include studio.h>"
"#include stdlib.h>"

These library should be included in your files.